# PhpStorm to support registry pattern

Tags: phpstorm

In my code I use Registry pattern like that:

```
$data = Registry::get('classA')->methodOfClassA($param1, param2);
```

Registry class stores instances of some classes in internal array, so in any place of my code I can call class methods for handy functions like in line above.

But, the problem is that PHP-storm does not autocomplete when I type:

```
Registry::get('classA')->
```

And, that is worse, it does not go to declaration of the method "methodOfClassA" when I hover mouse cursor holding mac-button (analogue of control-button on windows)

I suppose, that IDE AI is not so good to recognise cases like that, but maybe there is some tricks to do that in a hard way? hardcoding classes+method names in some file and so on...

At least, I want it to understand to go to method declaration when I click method name...

Any advices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata

This link describes it all -- it is already used by multiple projects/frameworks/code-generation helpers, like Magento, for example (some other can be found mentioned in the comments of the actual ticket).

For other situations you may want to check out **DynamicReturnTypePlugin** plugin (`Settings | Plugins | Browse repositories...`) -- have not tried myself and therefore cannot comment how good/fast/laggy it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can always indicate the variable type in two steps:

```
/** @var $foo MyClass */
$foo = $this->get('MyClass');
$foo->bar(); // autocomplete works
```